# C++ - Array value becomes 1 after being read

Tags: c++, arrays

So, I'm running a pretty trivial and bare-bones piece of code:

```
template <typename T>
matrix<T>::matrix(int r, int c, int a)
{
   int data2[6*4] = {-1, 12, 23, 34, 45, 56,
                     11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66,
                     21, 32, 43, 54, 65, -1,
                     31, 42, 53, 64, -1, -1};

    mData = new T(6*4);

    for(int p=0; p < 6*4; p++){
        mData[p] = T(data2[p]);
        std::cout << " " << mData[p] << ":";
        std::cout << " " << mData[p] << ":" << std::endl; //second time is read
    };

    for(int p=0; p < 4; p++){
        for(int p2=0; p2 < 6; p2++){
            if(mData[p2 + p * 6] == 1)std::cout << "FOUND ONE" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    int i = 6;
    matrix<int> b = matrix<int>(i,i, 0);
}
```

However, at random intervals there are times where a value of a data CHANGES to 1 the second time it's being read. It's never the first time, always the second one. Here you have an example:

```
-1: -1:                                                                                                                                 
12: 12:                                                                                                                     
23: 23:                                                                                                                 
34: 34:                                                                                                                 
45: 45:                                                                                                                         
56: 56:                                                                                                                 
11: 11:                                                                                                                 
22: 22:                                                                                                                 
33: 1:                                                                                                                  
44: 44:                                                                                                                 
55: 55:                                                                                                                 
66: 66:                                                                                                                 
21: 21:                                                                                                                 
32: 32:                                                                                                                 
43: 43:                                                                                                                    
54: 54:                                                                                                                 
65: 65:                                                                                                                 
-1: -1:                                                                                                                 
31: 31:                                                                                                                 
42: 42:                                                                                                                 
53: 53:                                                                                                                 
64: 64:                                                                                                                 
-1: -1:                                                                                                                 
-1: -1:                                                                                                                
FOUND ONE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.085 s                                                                     
Press any key to continue.
```

There is nothing else touching the structure, so I have no idea what could be going on. The number is always saved properly (since the first print is ALWAYS correct), but afterwards it gets corrupted... I got no idea what's going any. Any help?

EDIT:

Solution found, apparently I simply mistook a "[]" for a "()", and despite looking the code over and over never noticed. (it's obvious at hindsight).

Thank you guys.

Comment: I suspect your class does not follow the Rule of Three, and you are actually accessing deleted memory. Please post a MCVE

Comment: I have a hunch (but really not sure), that you are not initializing your `mData` correctly. I think you are just initializing it as a single integer in this case, so my guess is that when you offset with `mData[p]` and set a value, sometimes that value gets changed before you read it because the memory at `mData[p]` it is not reserved. Maybe `std::vector<T> mData`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line of code:

```
mData = new T(6*4);
```

a single instance of T is allocated. Afterwards, the code tries to access that as an array, leading to out of bounds access.

It was probably intended like this:

```
mData = new T[6*4];
```

---

Edit and another tip: In order to reduce error like these and to improve the overall code style, I almost always go for `std::vector<T>` instead of `T*` when creating arrays of elements. The access pattern rarely changes in code but you don't need to worry about memory management and gain additional bonus methods for almost no costs.

Comment: And this is why `new` should be considered a "pros only" technique and not taught to novices.

Comment: @MooingDuck I diasgree.  Make 'em learn early and learn correctly.  :)

Comment: @MooingDuck Sadly, I have been using C++ for years every now and then, so I would consider my self a beginer. (Not a novice) I agree that new is something that can be toxic if you don't know how to handle it. However, I have to make a code with big emphazis on performance, so having control of when memory is created is very useful.

Comment: @HeroicKatora Thanks a lot dude. You are a real hero. :) I read my code over 500 times, and I couldn't notice that small mistake. I SHOULD KNOW THIS, and yet I was so frustrated that I kept missing it. As I sad above, bear in mind that my code should perform incredibly well, so using vector could be a drawback, even if it's a great library.

Comment: @NacOverflow The only drawback of `std::vector` in terms of performance I can think of is that its size is typically `3*sizeof(void*)` instead of `sizeof(void*)`. But if c++14 is available to you, you could do `std::unique_ptr<T[]> mData = std::make_unique<T[]>(6*4)`, gaining real zero cost semantic improvements.